# Грамматические правила русского языка для сущ. очки, ножницы, брюки и др

Tags: грамматика, недопустимая-метка, правила

Почему числительные 2, 3, 4 не могут сочетаться с существительными очки, носилки, ножницы, брюки?

Comment: Что за загадочное слово в вашем перечислении? И второе: почему же не сочетаются? Очень даже, как и все остальные числительные.

Answer (score 2):

1. Числительные ***два, три, четыре***  в И.-В. падеже сочетаются с существительными в форме Р.п. в **единственном**, а не во множественном числе, как другие: *два стола, три тетради, четыре урока, но пять стульев.*
2. Существительными ***очки, носилки, ножницы, брюки*** имеют форму только **множественного числа**, их называют **[Pluralia tantum](https://gufo.me/dict/linguistics_rosenthal/pluralia_tantiun)** (с лат. — «множественные только»).
3. В счетных оборотах  с существительными pluralia tantum, а также обозначающими парные предметы используются не количественные, а **собирательные** числительные: **двое ножниц, четверо суток, трое ботинок** (три пары ботинок).

   ```
    В наборе двое ножниц. В прокат вышел фильм «трое суток 
    после бессмертия». К храму ведут четверо ворот.
   ```

**Примечание.** Форма «одни» используется как количественное числительное только при счете предметов, употребляемых во множественном числе: **одни сутки, одни ножницы.**

4. Но собирательное числительное используется только **в И.-В. падеже,** в остальных косвенных падежах используются **количественные** числительные:

И.-В. **двое ножниц, двое саней, через двое суток** –
собирательные числительные в И.-В. падеже;

Р. Д. Т. П. **в течение двух суток, на двух санях, к
двум воротам, с тремя ножницами** – количественные
числительные в косвенных падежах.

```
   Императорский поезд – карета и двое саней – отъезжает от 
   дворца. Через двое суток шторм обернется тайфуном. 
   Продолжавшийся около двух суток снегопад перекрыл все 
   дороги. Дорога подходила к двум главным воротам города.
   Норвежцы прибыли на двух санях и одиннадцати собаках.
```

5. Собирательные числительные ***дое, трое, четверо*** никогда не включаются в **составные** числительные.  В этом случае делается или **замена** существительного, или **переход** к косвенным падежам, где можно использовать **количественные**, а не собирательные числительные:

Этот рейс продолжался 24 (суток) – Этот рейс продолжался 24 дня – **замена слова** сутки словом день. Этот рейс продолжался в течение двадцати **четырех** суток – **замена винительного падежа** родительным. В **деловом** стиле уместны следующие выражения: двадцать две штуки ножниц. Приобретены сани в количестве двадцати **двух** штук.

Comment: Простите, *Sharon*, не поняла Ваш второй четвертый пункт. **26 суток** (двадцать шесть суток) — это нормально, грамотно.  Зачем тут какие-то замены, где же здесь собирательное числительное? • *Депутаты утвердят продление режима чрезвычайного положения в Приднестровье на 26 суток – до 1 мая*. • *Первый полет Мусабаева состоялся в 1994 году в возрасте 43 лет и продлился без малого 126 суток*.

Comment: Спасибо, исправлю. Недоработка дизайна.  Я сама вчера заметила, но не стала исправлять (за ответ уже проголосовали).  Думаю, все равно никто не читает, пиши не пиши, и так сойдет) Но здесь такие редакторы...

Comment: Кстати, новым участникам лучше вообще не отвечать. Они или не читают ответ, или читают и молча уходят. Ответ не принимают, спасибо не скажут, дополнительный вопрос не зададут.

Comment: Давайте все не будем отвечать новым участникам! В чём же тогда смысл нашего здесь присутствия? Мне Ваши рассуждения не подходят (*пиши не пиши, и так сойдет*). Несмотря на то, что Ваш ответ положительно оценен, я прошу Вас исправить его еще раз. *4. Собирательные числительные **два, три, четыре**никогда не включаются в составные числительные.* **Нет** *таких* собирательных числительных.

Comment: Точно, нет!  Это же количественные числительные!  Опять недоработочка. Текст, знаете, сложный.  Другие бы два предложения написали и голоса бы получили от двух до пяти, а то и больше.  А мне одна критика достается.  У меня половина ответов с нулевым рейтингом.  Да еще минусовки каждый день. Надо перестраиваться!  И картинки больше рисовать не буду,  и текст решительно сокращаю.  Тогда и ошибок будет меньше.

Comment: Удалить бы надо, ведь новому участнику мой ответ не пригодился.  Пишу непонятно, надо новую редакцию попробовать (из трех предложений).   А вы уж отвечайте по своим правилам. Мне вот тоже не нравится, когда ответ без  ссылок на источники (по типу я так думаю). Это же мнение, а не ответ.  Из одних примеров правило не выведешь, это задача лингвистов,  а не наша.  Но людям нравятся такие ответы.  С меня голоса снимают (за теорию какую-никакую, за новую терминологию),  а вам отдают.  Вероятно, им и так сойдет. как у вас. Это что касается ваших правильных рассуждений и поучений о нашем долге.

Comment: Но ведь в Вашем ответе вообще нет никаких ссылок, кроме разъяснения что такое * pluralia tantum*. ***Как*** же тогда воспринимать представленную в ответе информацию — это ваши собственные рассуждения или взято из каких-то источников? Получается, что от других требуем, а себя не видим?

Comment: Какие там мои рассуждения!  Я себе такое не позволяю, только из источников списываю.  Это  взято из Русской грамматики, 1990 года.  А также этот материал  есть в школьных учебниках, например: Гольцова.  Русский язык 10 – 11 класс,  2007 год, 4-е издание.  Я просто конспектик составила, удобный для работы.  Я думала, вы знаете.

Comment: А я-то здесь при чем? Вы ведь не мне отвечали. Всем.

Comment: Вроде бы не вам, а новому участнику. Но я думаю, вы-то все это знаете: источников много, общеизвестная информация, вот и не дала ссылку. Но есть темы, где без ссылок  никак.